# Why can't emulation ROMS just be recompiled to x86?

Tags: emulation

I've wondered this for a while. Why can't you just take a binary ROM of for example a NES or N64 ROM, and just convert the executable parts from MIPS or 6502 to x86 assembly? I mean all the opcodes are covered anyway.
I know theres a handful of ARM codes that can't be converted over, but for consoles up until the WII, couldn't one just convert the assembly code and intercept IO stuff like rendering and gamepad input?
Because it feels like that would speed up emulation considerably.

Comment: Imagine you translated all the opcodes. What about the hardware and the targeted OS handling?

Comment: like I said that could be intercepted, just as it is done now, just on top of a virtual machine.

Comment: You have to reproduce as exactly as possible the behavior of a source system, including hardware level stuff (real time screen operations, specific-shaped sound signal, clock speed, etc.) which could be very complex. It's not like an opcode table and IO interceptions would resolve.